# Combining environments in two packages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzducks

I made a graph using the tikz package and want to use the tikzducks package to make vertices of the graph. (In particular, I want to replace the points at vertices of an arbitrary graph with colored ducks). Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
\node[main] (1) {}; 
\node[main] (2) [above right of=1] {} ; 
\node[main] (3) [below right of=1] {} ;
\node[main] (4) [above right of=3] {} ; 
\node[main] (5) [above right of=4] {} ; 
\node[main] (6) [below right of=4] {} ; 
\draw (1) -- (2); 
\draw (1) -- (3); 
\draw (1) to [out=135,in=90,looseness=1.5] (5); 
\draw (1) to [out=180,in=270,looseness=5] (1); 
\draw (2) -- (4); 
\draw (3) -- (4); 
\draw (5) -- (4); 
\draw (5) to [out=315, in=315, looseness=2.5] (3); 
\draw (6) -- node[midway, above right, sloped, pos=1] {} (4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: A lovely idea! Can you share how you made the graph (with normal markers). I'm sure we will then do our best to add the ducks :)

Comment: (there are several ways how to draw a graph in tikz, it would be really helpful to see a short, but compilable test document so we know which of the possible approaches you are using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the normal `tikzducks` package, there is also a tikz library which allows you to use the ducks as tikz `pic`s:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,ducks}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance={15mm}, 
  thick, main/.style = {},
  quack/.style = {scale=0.15,xshift=-0.8cm,yshift=-0.8cm}
] 
\node[main] (1) {}; 
\node[main] (2) [above right of=1] {} ; 
\node[main] (3) [below right of=1] {} ;
\node[main] (4) [above right of=3] {} ; 
\node[main] (5) [above right of=4] {} ; 
\node[main] (6) [below right of=4] {} ; 

\pic[quack] at (1) {duck};
\pic[quack] at (2) {duck};
\pic[quack,duck/body=red] at (3) {duck};
\pic[quack] at (4) {duck};
\pic[quack,duck/body=green] at (5) {duck};
\pic[quack] at (6) {duck};

\draw (1) -- (2); 
\draw (1) -- (3); 
\draw (1) to [out=135,in=90,looseness=1.5] ([yshift=7pt]5); 
\draw (1) to [out=180,in=270,looseness=5] (1); 
\draw (2) -- (4); 
\draw (3) -- (4); 
\draw (5) -- (4); 
\draw (5) to [out=315, in=315, looseness=2.5] (3); 
\draw (6) -- node[midway, above right, sloped, pos=1] {} (4); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the poor green duck ;-(

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I gave the green duck a bit more room :)